# using os.path.expanduser("~") I am getting /root instead of /home/pi

Tags: python, linux

While logged in as "standard" pi user, I am expecting the path to the user directory to be /home/pi – which is the case when I open File Manager, for example. However, when I run this script I get /root instead of the expected /home/pi:

```
import os

homedir = os.path.expanduser("~")
print (homedir)
```

Is my assumption wrong ?
What (else) should I use to get the pi user directory ?

**Edit**: I found the answer by myself: this happens because I am running the Python script prefixed with sudo. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: Are you sure you are not running the script as root?  You have probaly started the script or its environment with sudo.  The script shows my home directory if I start it without sudo.  It shows /root if I start it with sudo.

Comment: Yes, I realized that minutes after. Wrong doing on my part, sorry. And thank you for pointing this also :)

Comment: If you've figured the answer to your question, please submit it as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

By running the script prefixed with *sudo* the script is running as super user, whose home directory is /root.

In order to get the current user home directory (/home/pi in this case) the script should be run directly, i.e. as pi user but not prefixed with *sudo*.

Comment: You can configure sudo to preserve the HOME environment variable which  would allow the other behavior.

Comment: That means changing the behavior of the system ? (for that user) If yes (?), then no, I prefer this to remain an application-specific approach. For this purpose I used `sudo_username = os.getenv("SUDO_USER")` `home_dir = "/home/" + sudo_username` which is mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5754477)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this piece of code as an **Alternative solution**.

```py
from subprocess import check_output

homedir: str = check_output('pwd').decode('utf-8')

print(homedir)
```

This block of code `check_output('pwd').decode('utf-8')` should give you the path of the user file, Which is `/home/USER_NAME` even if you use `sudo` command to run this program.